# Android app and java activities, issues with onCreate() method and XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I am trying use the onClick() function in an activity for an android app.  So far I have:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ImageButton closeButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wowButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        this.closeButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.close);
        this.closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
            }
        });   
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView lowerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        EditText boxText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        lowerText.setText(boxText.getText());       
    }

}
```

This is just a stripped down version of my project.  When I enter my app as usual in the emualtor, everything works fine.  When I click the button to open up this particular activity, everything crashes.  I assume the issue lies within the onClick() method.  This code was sent to me by my project partner without the XML files so I think thats where the problem lies.

here is my basic XML file that I thought should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/wowButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" android:text="WoW" android:typeface="sans"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_default_normal_red" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

While very basic, I though it should work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you show the stack trace with the exception?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.devtracker/com.app.devtracker.Activity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException   ... Which evetually leads to "@onClick" as I initially thought.

Comment: try to set a breakpoint in the onClick method and check to see what went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you instantiate an ImageButton through `this.closeButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.close);`
 But you don't declare it in the xml file. That's why it's null and throws a NullPointer Exception.

Comment: There's no instantiation happening in a `findViewById` call, `findViewById` only searches for views that already exist in the hierarchy. It will return `null` when the view isn't found though, which does indeed cause a NullPointerException on the next line.

Comment: wow sorry for wasting your time... The activity I had was new to my project, and I wanted that close button in each new activity, but I forgot to do the same in the XML.

Comment: @adamp: yes, it's not instantiating. Sorry for my poor theoretical explanation. It is initializing, right?

Comment: The view is already initialized in the sense that it's been constructed and is fully functional within the view hierarchy, though the app may still hook up listeners, alter state, etc. later. If you consider that part of your app's process of 'initializing' its UI, then sure. :)